# Resizing and stretching a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, resize, numpy, stretch

I am working in Python and I have a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array like this:

```
[1,5,9]
[2,7,3]
[8,4,6]
```

How do I stretch it to something like the following?

```
[1,1,5,5,9,9]
[1,1,5,5,9,9]
[2,2,7,7,3,3]
[2,2,7,7,3,3]
[8,8,4,4,6,6]
[8,8,4,4,6,6]
```

These are just some example arrays, I will actually be resizing several sizes of arrays, not just these.

I'm new at this, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around what I need to do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

@KennyTM's answer is very slick, and really works for your case but as an alternative that might offer a bit more flexibility for expanding arrays try [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 5, 9],
              [2, 7, 3],
              [8, 4, 6]])

>>> np.repeat(a,2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])
```

So, this accomplishes repeating along one axis, to get it along multiple axes (as you might want), simply nest the `np.repeat` calls:

```
>>> np.repeat(np.repeat(a,2, axis=0), 2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])
```

You can also vary the  number of repeats for any initial row or column.  For example, if you wanted two repeats of each row aside from the last row:

```
>>> np.repeat(a, [2,2,1], axis=0)
array([[1, 5, 9],
       [1, 5, 9],
       [2, 7, 3],
       [2, 7, 3],
       [8, 4, 6]])
```

Here when the second argument is a `list` it specifies a row-wise (rows in this case because `axis=0`) repeats for each row.

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,5,9],[2,7,3],[8,4,6]])
>>> numpy.kron(a, [[1,1],[1,1]])
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])
```

Comment: In case someone's wondering, it's the Kronecker product: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html

Comment: as cool as this answer is, it takes twice as long as the repeat method in dtlussier's answer on my machine for big arrays

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately numpy does not allow fractional steps (as far as I am aware).  Here is a workaround.  It's not as clever as Kenny's solution, but it makes use of traditional indexing:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,5,9],[2,7,3],[8,4,6]])
>>> step = .5
>>> xstop, ystop = a.shape
>>> x = numpy.arange(0,xstop,step).astype(int)
>>> y = numpy.arange(0,ystop,step).astype(int)
>>> mg = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
>>> b = a[mg].T
>>> b
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])
```

(dtlussier's solution is better)