# What is the opposite of numpy.repeat?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226386/resizing-and-stretching-a-numpy-array) explains how to resize an array from

```
[1,5,9]
[2,7,3]
[8,4,6]
```

to

```
[1,1,5,5,9,9]
[1,1,5,5,9,9]
[2,2,7,7,3,3]
[2,2,7,7,3,3]
[8,8,4,4,6,6]
[8,8,4,4,6,6]
```

using `np.repeat`. Given the lower array, what is the best way to shrink it to the upper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Slice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) across both axes with appropriate stepsize -

```
a[::2,::2] # 2 being stepsize here
```

Sample run -

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])

In [24]: a[::2,::2]
Out[24]: 
array([[1, 5, 9],
       [2, 7, 3],
       [8, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score -1):

> np.repeat(a, repeats, axis=None)

Repeat elements of an array.

input :

```
a = 

np.array([[1,5,9],
[2,7,3],
[8,4,6]])
print (a)
```

output:

```
Out[76]: 
array([[1, 5, 9],
       [2, 7, 3],
       [8, 4, 6]])
```

using `np.repeat`

```
In [78]: b = np.repeat(a,[2],axis = 1)

In [79]: b
Out[79]: 
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])

In [80]: c = np.repeat(b,[2],axis = 0)

In [81]: c
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6]])
```